# How to correctly coordinate Windows load animations and C# events?

Tags: wpf, window

My WPF application has a window load animation which I created using Blend. The actual animation works fine, but if I add logic to my window load event (using C#) the animation skips to end when the window finally renders.

My initial plan was to use Threading to solve this, but this too didn't work:

```
private void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();

    lstRecipients.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; 
    windowAdorner = new TransparentAdorner(BorderGrid);

    if (!StaticHelpers.AWSConfigurationExists())
    {
        this.IsEnabled = false;
        GettingStarted gettingStarted = new GettingStarted(this);
        gettingStarted.Owner = this;
        gettingStarted.ShowDialog();
        this.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Task SetAWSLabelsTask = new Task(new Action(() => SetAWSLabels()));
        SetAWSLabelsTask.Start();

    }

    Task bounceHandler = new Task(new Action(() => processBounce()));
    bounceHandler.Start();
    //processBounce();

    Task unSubscribeHandler = new Task(new Action(() => handleUnsubscriptions()));
    unSubscribeHandler.Start(); 
}
```

I'm assuming the system is so busy creating the threads, and the creation is handled by the UI thread, that the animation has already finished by the time the Window is rendered.

What I'm missing is a good way to coordinate the animation, so that any business logic I have in MyWindow_Loaded occurs only after the animation has finished loading.

Is this possible?

EDIT: I also tried a thread sleep, and this too didn't work.

Comment: can you move the animation to OnActivate (sp?)?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks John, didn't know about the SEO behind the scenes, very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Solved the problem.

In the XAML added a new event handler to the storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="SESLogoLoad" Completed="StoryCompleted">
```

Then created a method manually using C#:

```
private void StoryCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Windows onload stuff goes here...
}
```